# Affine Spaces with weakened closedness criteria

Tags: linear-algebra

We need to show that a non-empty set $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed w.r.t. taking two term affine combinations, i.e.

$$ x,y \in M \implies \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in M$$

is an Affine Subspace.

I can prove this statement if we are allowed general affine combinations (of more than 2 terms) but when we have this weakened property I'm finding it difficult to prove this statement.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show by induction on $n$, that 
$$ x_i \in M, \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 1 \implies \sum_i \lambda_i x_i \in M $$
For $n = 1$ this is trivially true, for $n = 2$ this is true by asumption. Now suppose $n \ge 3$ and this holds for $n-1$. W.l.o.g. suppose $\lambda_n \ne 1$, for there is some $i$ with $\lambda_i \ne 1$, by permuting we can acchieve it's $n$. Now define $\mu_i := \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_n}$ for $i < n$, then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu_i = \frac 1{1- \lambda_n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i = 1 $$
hence, by induction hypothesis, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu_i x_i \in M$, therefore, by assumption
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i = \lambda_n x_n + (1-\lambda_n) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu_i x_i \in M. $$